# Time complexity of this code? (Product of Array Except Self)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I'm having trouble figuring out the time complexity of this code. It looks like it's linear time to me because of the for-loops, but I'm thinking the numpy.prod together with the outer for loops will cause it to run n^2. What do you think?

import numpy

```
class Solution:

    def productExceptSelf(self, arr):

        arr = numpy.array(arr)
        length = len(arr)

        l = numpy.zeros(len(arr))
        l[0] = 1

        r = numpy.zeros(len(arr))
        r[length-1] = 1



        for i in range(1,len(arr)):
            l[i] = numpy.prod(arr[:i])

        for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
            r[i] = numpy.prod(arr[i+1:])

        for i in range(0,len(arr)):
            arr[i] = l[i] * r[i]

        return arr
```

Comment: Definitely n^2.

Comment: why? @Błotosmętek

Comment: `numpy.prod` **is** a loop, only implemented in C rather than in Python. Still, as you observed, `prod` inside of `for` loop is equivalent to double loop, except the inner one is much optimized.

Comment: If you do not always start the product calculation from start but continue from previous iteration then you can implement it in `O(n)`